# How do I shift an array to the left into a new array?

Tags: java, arrays, shift

Write a loop that sets newScores to oldScores shifted once left, with element 0 copied to the end. Ex: If oldScores = {10, 20, 30, 40}, then newScores = {20, 30, 40, 10}.

**This is my code**

What am I missing in order to shift it to the left? My output is the same as the input.

````
   public class StudentScores {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
      int[] oldScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int[] newScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < oldScores.length; ++i) {
          oldScores[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }
      for (i = oldScores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
           newScores[i] = oldScores[i];
      }
      for (i = 0; i < newScores.length; ++i) {
          System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
      }
          System.out.println();
   }
}```
````

Comment: `for (i = oldScores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` This is just a regular `for` loop but in reverse.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < oldScores.length; ++i) { newScores[i] = oldScores[(i + 1) % SCORES_SIZE]; }`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about the first element, it should be in the last place and you don't need a second array, you can just move all the elements to the left side except the first one.